# How can I improve my multiple “if and else if” VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a series of data and depending on it I have to decide if it's a TE or LE edge. I have several conditions which I tried to sum up in the following code.
The code is working but I have some blank spaces left which means certain conditions are not taken into account.

More specifically I think it's this one:

```
ElseIf Val(Range("G" & i).Value) > 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "TE"
```

Guess it's a problem of all this If and ElseIf but I couldn't find a solution to it.

So let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you.

```
Sub edge()

On Error Resume Next

Dim lastRowIndex As Integer
Dim firstRowIndex As Integer
Dim MyString As String


lastRowIndex = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

MyString = Application.ThisCell.Address
firstRowIndex = Range(MyString).Select

For i = firstRowIndex To lastRowIndex
If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 1).Value Then
            If Range("G" & i).Value > Range("G" & i + 1).Value Then
                    If Range("H" & i).Value = "0" Then Range("N" & i).Value = "TE"
                    ElseIf 0.01898 < Val(Range("G" & i).Value) < 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "LE"
                    **ElseIf Val(Range("G" & i).Value) > 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "TE"**
                    End If

            ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value < Range("G" & i + 1).Value Then
                    If Range("H" & i).Value = "0" Then Range("N" & i).Value = "LE"
                    ElseIf 0.01898 < Val(Range("G" & i).Value) < 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "LE"
                    ElseIf Val(Range("G" & i).Value) > 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "TE"
                    End If



ElseIf i Mod 2 = 0 Then
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then
            If Range("G" & i).Value > Range("G" & i - 1).Value Then
                    If Range("H" & i).Value = "0" Then Range("N" & i).Value = "TE"
                    ElseIf 0.01898 < Val(Range("G" & i).Value) < 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "LE"
                    ElseIf Val(Range("G" & i).Value) > 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "TE"

            ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value < Range("G" & i - 1).Value Then
                    If Range("H" & i).Value = "0" Then Range("N" & i).Value = "LE"
                    ElseIf 0.01898 < Val(Range("G" & i).Value) < 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "LE"
                    ElseIf Val(Range("G" & i).Value) > 0.02149 Then Range("N" & i).Value = "TE"
            End If
    End If
End If


Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. There are some cases that are not supported by your code. What if:

1. `Range("A" & i).Value <> Range("A" & i + 1).Value`
2. `Range("G" & i).Value = Range("G" & i + 1).Value`
3. `Val(Range("G" & i).Value) < 0.01898`
4. `Val(Range("G" & i).Value) = 0.02149`

Also, you can't use two inequalities in one `If` statement in the way you did it. Use `And` instead, like

```
ElseIf 0.01898 < Val(Range("G" & i).Value) And Val(Range("G" & i).Value) < 0.02149 Then
```

And you don't have to use `ElseIf` with condition opposite to `If`, just use `Else`:

```
If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then
    ...
Else
    ...
```